# Indenting Syntax Highlighter when starting with a php echo

Tags: php, javascript, formatting, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I am using Alex Gorbatchev's [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to output some code, but I'm getting an issue where it's not retaining the initial indentation if I start the line with a php echo.  For example where I would expect the following:

```
<pre class="brush: php;">
    <?php
        echo $variable->getScope() . " ";
        echo $variable->getName();
    ?>;
</pre>
```

to output the following:

```
    protected $variable;
```

it instead outputs the following:

```
protected $variable;
```

losing the indented four spaces.  If I add a piece of static text on the line above it retains the spaces as intended.

I've also tried changing the third line to the following:

```
echo "    ".$variable->getScope() . " ";
```

which also has no effect.  Here is the javascript where I am initialising Syntax Highlighter:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['gutter'] = false;
SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['toolbar'] = false;
SyntaxHighlighter.all()
```

To clarify, the highlighter is functioning as expected in every other way.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax highlighter will indent the code, and it sees your code is in no bracket and so it does not indent. Code in a function will e.g. get indented.

Comment: This does kind of seem to be the issue - it appears that the highlighter only adds formatting when it is in relation to another line, so if there is only one line all the indentation will be removed.

Comment: I'm sure it indends your code automatically. Try `\n{\npublic $var;\n}`

Comment: It doesn't seem to, it only indents when it is indented relative to another line.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it led to the issue which was that code that is not in relation to anything does not indent.